# How to use PowerShell workflows and checkpoints for resumability

Tags: powershell, workflow, resume, checkpoint, phase

I'm building a monolithic PowerShell "developer-machine-setup" script that installs various packages, configures various things, checks out repos, builds them etc etc.

It breaks down naturally into a number of "phases", some long-running others very quick to execute. It's designed to fail-fast in case of errors (do not pass go, do not collect $200).

The code in the phases is a mixture of executing various commandlets and (where no suitable commandlet exists) executing external processes.

I've currently structured the script as a bunch of functions (one for each "phase") and a wrapper function that executes the phase functions in sequence.

I'd like the script to sensibly handle "resuming" a phase when re-run (i.e. someone runs the script, it reports an error, user corrects the error condition & re-runs the script - the script should continue from the last "committed" phase).

Is this something I can do with Workflow/Commit-Checkpoint/InlineScript? I could roll my own checkpointing functionality (i.e. write something to a JSON file or allow the user to specify the phase on the command-line) but want to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/system-center/sma/overview-powershell-workflows?view=sc-sma-2019

Comment: @f6a4: I'd read that documentation already, didn't really answer my question (hence posting on SO)